# How to edit tooltip in superset chart

Tags: tooltip, linechart, apache-superset

I'm new to superset and discovering whether it is available to edit the tooltip in a line chart.
For example the line chart is with *date* as x-axis and *price* as y-axis, so the tooltip only shows these two information. But I want the tooltip also showing the *cost* without adding it to the chart. Is it able to accomplish it in superset?